# Inductive and reducible functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, computer-science, semigroups-and-monoids

The question was asked by a Computer Scientist and is closely related to parallel computing. But it is clearly of algebraic nature, so I decided to post it here.

Let $X$ be a set and $\bar X$ be the union of all Cartesian powers $X^n$.
Let $f$ be a function from $\bar X$ to $X$. We say that $f$ is *inductive* if
there exists a binary operation $F\colon  X\times X \to X$  such that for
every $x_1,...,x_n \in X$, $n>1$, we have
$f(x_1,...,x_n)=F(f(x_1,...,x_{n-1}), x_n)$. If, in addition, $F$ is
associative and $(X,F)$ is a monoid (has the identity element), then $f$
is called *reducible*. For example, if $X$ is the set of all natural
numbers,  $f$ is the max function on $\bar X$, then we can take
$F(x,y)=\max(x,y)$. So $f$ is reducible.

We say that $(X,f)$ has an *inductive (resp. reducible) extension* if
there exists a set $Y$ containing $X$ with a function $g$ from $\bar Y$ to $Y$
and a projection function $p: Y\to X$ such that $$p(g(x_1,...,x_n))=f(x_1,...,x_n)$$ for
all $x_1,...,x_n$ in $X$ and $(Y, g)$ is inductive (resp. reducible).

**Question:** 1) What is known about the set of functions $f$ with inductive
(reducible) extensions? 2) In particular, does every function $f$ admit an 
inductive (reducible) extension?

Comment: Besides being notationally convenient, is there a reason to consider f as a function on Xbar (sorry not up to formatting right now) as opposed to a schema of functions f_n which turn out to be term functions in F and a starting unary function?  I think the opposing view might lead to find non inductive (non reducible) f.  Gerhard "Better To Work With Many" Paseman, 2017.04.16.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman:  It might be reasonable to view $f$ as a collection of $f_n$. Indeed, $f_n$ is a term of $F$, but it is not an arbitrary term. In any case, then the question is about describing all collections of $f_n$ which come this way from some extension of $X$.

Comment: Exercise 10, chapter 4.1 in MMT's Algebras Lattices Varieties Vol I. seems related and may be relevant. Unfortunately I can't judge how relevant right now. Gerhard "Too Tired To Think Clearly" Paseman, 2017.04.16.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: It is not the same, but this exercise may mean that the answer to Question 2) is "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $\bar X$ also contains $\varnothing$ as the Cartesian product of 0 copies of $X$.

Set $Y=\bar X$. If $y_i=(x_{i,1},\dots,x_{i,k_i})\in X^{k_i}$ with $i=1,\dots,\ell$, set
$$
  g(y_1,\dots,y_\ell)=(x_{1,1},\dots,x_{1,k_1},x_{2,1},\dots,x_{2,k_2},\dots)\in X^{k_1+k_2+\dots}\subset Y
$$
(so $g$ is simply the concatenation). Clearly, $g$ is reducible (with $F$ being a binary concatenation; we get a monoid, since we added $\varnothing$). Finally, for $y=(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ define 
$$
  p(y)=f(x_1,\dots,x_k)
$$
(we can define $p(\varnothing)$ arbitrarily; on the other elements, $p$ does all the job).
Thus we obtain a reducible extension of $f$.

So, each function $f$ indeed has a reducible extension.

Comment: Yes, it is correct and answers my question. It is not what CS people want because this reducibility would not make their life easier, Surely some computational complexity theory should be involved. When I know what they want exactly, I will post another question.

Comment: Perhaps, they need $Y$ to be small? (E.g., finite when $X$ is finite?)

Comment: That is what I suggested too, but it is not the only condition.